# Trouble using GWT ScrollPanel

Tags: java, layout, gwt, scroll

I'm trying to show a large image inside of a `ScrollPanel`. The `ScrollPanel` is one of the tabs of a `TabPanel`. All this is inside of a `VerticalSplitPanel`.

I expected to have the `ScrollPanel` doing the scrolling but instead it is the `VerticalSplitPanel` that has the scrollbars.

Can anybody help me achieve the desired behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is, because I don't know what your css and/or code looks, that the ScrollPanel doesn't have a fixed height, and expands with the content in height. The VerticalSplitPanel probably has a fixed height (or due to its context gets a fixed height), and gets the scrollbar. In such a case, setting a height on the ScollBar will probably fix it.